# Is there a tablet for programming in the market today?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need a tablet that could do Python (CPython), Java, C, C++ (also embedding) programming.

So suppose that I would use android arm tablet for that and install Ubuntu on it. What I don't know would I be able to compile for arm on arm with `gcc` when I'm doing embedded programming? And Would Cython work on arm?

And if there is fully capable Linux tablet with specs of a surface pro 3 than it would be great, I guess.

Comment: AFAIK you still need to do the programming yourself. Cython generates C code, not sure why would you think this cannot be compiled with arm as a target

Comment: Because Cython itself is written in C. And so there have to be arm binary to use it on arm. Is there?

Comment: If Cython was only in C, there still doesn't have to be a binary, your requirement that you can compile C programs takes care of being able to compile any programs. But you are wrong about Cython, most if not all of it is written in Python  and only requires python to run, the C output needs to be compiled. Maybe you are mixing up Cython and CPython?

Comment: Yes, I am. CPython what I meant.

Comment: Then you should update your question (as always with new information/corrections), as most people won't read through the comments

Comment: The shopping part of your question is OT. However, the latter part of your question is not about shopping. "What I don't know would I be able to compile for arm on arm with gcc when I'm doing embedded programming? And "Would Cython work on arm?" I'm not sure if this is on topic here, but I suggest you ask in the chat room. Note also that you should try as far as possible to only ask one question per posting. The "able to compile for arm on arm" bit strikes me as a little odd. gcc certainly works on arm. What else would you expect it to do but compile for arm on arm?

Comment: Well, I just never used it on arm. All tools for embedded programming are supposing that you are using cross compiler, you know? So I had doubts about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there are no tablets available the comes with Linux preinstalled. Canonical has plans to do one with Ubuntu which should be good for your purposes. In the meantime there are Linux installers on the Google Play store so you could install Linux on an Android tab. If you manage to do that you have access to all kinds of programming tools that you have on any other Linux installation.

Yes gcc can compile for all kinds of targets including arm. Cython is not dependent on the CPU architecture so that is not a problem either.